# Magento - Shipping rate per KG

Tags: magento

I am wondering if there is a way to calculate total shipping fee based on weight and in order to achieve that I may need to input how much per KG in somewhere, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default 'Table Rates' method allows you to do this.  Go to admin and navigate to;

System > Configuration (from the top menu)

Then go to 'Shipping Methods' (on the left menu)

Now, switch the view scope to your website in the top left drop down.  The page will reload.

In the main window, find 'Table Rates' and there will now be an 'export csv' button.  This only appears when you are on a website in the view scope.  Export it and enter your values, then reimport it.

Also make sure you change the 'Condition' setting in Table Rates to: 'Weight vs Destination'

Make sure all your products have a value for weight.  Magento doesn't discriminate on what measure of weight you use, it is simply a number, so as long as you enter the numeric KG value against the products and the shipping method, they will match.

Comment: That's cool, but where I can find all the country code defined? For example, Australia, China, what should I use?

Comment: Hi, take a look here: http://php.quicoto.com/magento-country-codes-for-table-rate/